# Passar código base64 para outra página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Já testei passar como get só que o código possui barra e da erro, preciso apenas passar o código base64 de uma pagina para outra página.

Obs** Este codigo base64 esta sendo gerado na página A com crop. E tenho que passar para a página B para outro tratamento.

Alguem teria alguma sugestão de como eu poderia fazer isso utilizando javascript/jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que tu podes utilizar a **sessionStorage**. Uma vez que tu estás trabalhando no lado do cliente e alguns cenários têm devem ser considerados.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

É simples a utilização da sessionStorage tanto para jquery quando javascript!

Comment: Cara se eu te contar que no momento que você enviou seu resposta eu estava lendo sobre a session do html5 kkk

Mais é isso mesmo, vou ter que utilizar ele mesmo... Obrigadão pela Ajuda...